# How do I referance and return a response based on answer of a radio button which is included within another radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

So far I have found out how to create radio buttons, hide the response until a selection is made and finally display the selection along with another radio button (this secondary radio button is where I'm stuck). Here is what I'd like:

A user selects yes/no:

If **Yes** selected

*Text appears below the radio buttons asking another yes/no question which results in more text based on answer and yes/no*

If **No** selected

*Different text appears below the radio buttons asking a different yes/no question which results in more text based on answer and yes/no*

I have been able to create the first yes/no which brings up another question and a yes/no radio button but I don't understand how to make responses for the second yes/no the one that comes up with the result of the first radio button.

I'm so sorry this is confusing but I don't know of any better way to explain it.

Here is my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richerdk/a9fJ5/

I'm assuming I need something like this:`<div id="div1" class="tab">
        <p>Why do you think the sky is blue, is blue your favorite colour?</p></div>` The issue is I don't know what the `<div id=" " class=" ">` should be.

The Yes/No buttons are located on lines 35,38,45,48 in the html portion of the jsfiddle and look like this `<input type="radio" name="another" value="anotherNo" />`

**My question is how do I get the radio button included in the response of the first radio button selection to display information based on its selection (yes or no).**

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My first advise is to use jQuery for this sort of manipulation. It's much simpler to read. My second advise is to change the title of your question, for obvious reasons

Comment: @Dogoku - you should've seen the original title

Comment: i did! that's the one i'm referring to

Comment: Edited sorry guys, I'm just really frustrated with this. I just want it completed so I can put it on my SharePoint and be done with it, as SharePoint surveys don't have a back button :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fork of your jsfiddle, with only the radio buttons and using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfxry/

---

What I did, was simply bind an event handler to the change events of the radio buttons inside tabs

```
(function ($) {
    $('#tabs').on('change',':radio', function () {
        //read target id from data attribute
        var targetId = $(this).data('target');
        //hide all tabs
        $('.tab').addClass('hidden');
        //show the one you want
        $("#"+targetId).removeClass('hidden');
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

**Note that I am now hiding the previous question**

There are a lot of way to improve the code. this is just a basic example

Comment: Thanks for your help, the only issue I have is that since the previous question is hidden if the user selects the wrong response there is no way to go back. The reason for this code is so that if a mistake is made a user can go back, as SharePoint surveys doesn't have a back button.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out which line to remove

Comment: I did '$('.tab').addClass('hidden');'
But then the response doesn't disappear if you select the wrong one ill be left with "Div 3" "Div 4"